# Why does my deployment terminate pods on deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a rolling update deployment strategy with a 0 max unavailable value.
Unfortunately when I deploy many pods get terminated and I am not sure why.

Example:

```
ScalingReplicaSet Scaled down replica set deployment-xyz to 27
ScalingReplicaSet Scaled down replica set deployment-xyz to 10
```

It went from 27 to 10 upon deployment

Strategy:

```
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  0 max unavailable, 25% max surge
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    component: app
  name: app
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 25
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - command
        image: image:tag
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: app
```

The HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  maxReplicas: 200
  minReplicas: 25
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: app
```

Where could I look to understand why this is happening?

Comment: Could you share your deployment yaml also? My suspicion is that you have set your replicas to 10, so when deploying you are essentially telling Kubernetes "I want 10 replicas, but you can scale up" -- so Kubernetes does that -- it scales the deployment down to 10 replicas as per your instruction.

Comment: Not sure why that's happening. I'll try to replicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have replicated your scenario by deploying 25 replicas of nginx and then triggering a rolling restart using:

```
kubectl patch deployment test-deployment \
  -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

This is the output:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                 From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----                ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  4m18s               deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set test-deployment-5c876b9587 to 25
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  82s                 deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set test-deployment-6765d87dcf to 7
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  80s                 deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set test-deployment-5c876b9587 to 24
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  80s                 deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set test-deployment-6765d87dcf to 8
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  80s                 deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set test-deployment-5c876b9587 to 23
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  80s                 deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set test-deployment-6765d87dcf to 9
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  80s                 deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set test-deployment-5c876b9587 to 22
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  80s                 deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set test-deployment-6765d87dcf to 10
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  80s                 deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set test-deployment-5c876b9587 to 21
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  77s (x16 over 80s)  deployment-controller  (combined from similar events): Scaled down replica set test-deployment-5c876b9587 to 11
```

It replicates your scenario almost exactly. Notice how the first two lines are:

```
Scaled up replica set test-deployment-5c876b9587 to 25
Scaled up replica set test-deployment-6765d87dcf to 7
```

What it's doing here is scaling up the initial set of 25 (after I deployed the deployment). The second line is when I triggered the update. It scales up 7 because 25% of 25 (your `maxSurge` value) is 6.25, so it rounds up to 7.

You can then see the rollout happening as it updates one pod at a time (terminating one pod from the old set, and bringing it up on the new set), since you specified 0 `maxUnavailable`, it won't terminate more than it's bringing up in the new replica set.

Looking at your original output:

```
ScalingReplicaSet Scaled down replica set deployment-xyz to 27
ScalingReplicaSet Scaled down replica set deployment-xyz to 10
```

I am not seeing any massive jumps in "scaled down" messages myself. Other than the last one where it jumps from 21 to 11, but it also says "Combined from similar events", meaning it's hidden messages from the event log because they are similar.

Are you able to share the exact event message log? (You can redact the deployment name if you wish, but keep the hashes visible as it's then possible to distinguish between the old and new replicasets)

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, OP was using Helm to deploy the changes, and that was setting replicas to 10, which caused the pods to drop from 25 to 10, then the HPA kicks in and scales it back up to 25, and then terminates those as the rollout progresses.

My recommendation is to make the HPA minReplicas AND the deployment replicas equal (use the same variable for both). Then you won't get caught out by this in future.

Comment: Scaled down replica set rs-current to 25;
Scaled down replica set rs-current to 10;
Scaled up replica set rs-new to 3;
Scaled up replica set rs-current to 25;
Scaled up replica set rs-new to 7;
Scaled up replica set rs-current to 29;
Scaled up replica set rs-new to 8;

Comment: Please can you add this to the question, along with the date/time bits at the start (see my answer above for example.) The timings may help establish the order of things. I am not 100% sure why your replica set is scaling down to 10 before scaling back up again to 25, unless something else in your cluster is scaling it down to 10.

Comment: Your initial suspicion was correct. My deployment has replicas set to 10 as a default in the helm chart value. So on every deployment the replicas property takes effect over the HPA. :( You can write a suiting answer to the question. I guess I have to disable/remove this property if the HPA is enabled?

Comment: Ah, you did not mention you were using Helm to do the deployment, or I would have suggested checking there :)

Comment: I have added an update to the answer in response to your additional information in your comment

Comment: An issue that comes to mind with the recommendation is that if the current replica count is 40 (15 above the minimum 25) then there still will be a dramatic unexpected/unwanted drop of replicas. So I am thinking of adding some logic in the helm templating so that the replicas property is only used if the HPA is not enabled, otherwise the HPA takes care of the replica count according to metrics or min replicas.

Comment: You still need to provide a replica count to the deployment. If it's below the min replicas value for the HPA, you get the drop as the deployment applies its change, then the jump as the HPA tries to recover it. So the two (deployment replicas and HPA min replicas) should be the same.

Comment: I tested it without the replicas property in the deployment. the deployment does not scale down on new deployment having the HPA controlling it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242004/discussion-between-blender-fox-and-adnan-mujkanovic).